# Difficulties setting up Application shortcuts in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore-client, application

I'm attempting to set up a shortcut in the Sitecore (8.1) start menu to an application (basically a custom `.aspx` page sitting within the `/sitecore` folder).  I've roughly followed [these instructions](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Customizing%20Sitecore%20Client/Adding%20an%20Application%20Shortcut.aspx) (and have paid attention to [this gotchya](https://sitecoreblog.marklowe.ch/2014/06/sitecore-start-menu-shortcuts-not-showing/)), but in detail I have done the following (all in the **core** database):

- Created a new Layout with the `Path` set to the relative URL of my .aspx page
- Created a new Application and assigned the new Layout in the Presentation Details
- Created a new Application Shortcut (within `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Programs`) linking to the Application item (making sure the raw value of the `Application` link includes the `url` attribute)

Sure enough, the shortcut appears in the start menu, but clicking it does nothing.  I've checked the network trace and the following is returned:

```
{"commands":
 [
  {"command":"SetAttribute","value":"/temp/iconcache/people/16x16/astrologer.png","id":"globalHeaderUserPortrait","name":"src"},
  {"command":"SetPipeline","value":"6CD9455F4EA6498F978F96D5A1CDD5E6"},
  {"command":"Eval","value":"scForm.browser.closePopups(\"Shell RunShortcut\")"}
 ]
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The link to the instructions page is unreachable to me. So I'm just going to explain how I've done it.

In the core db:

- Create a new layout under `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Custom Applications/` and set the path to the aspx page, starting from the website root (e.g. `/path/to/page.aspx` (note the forward slash at the start))
- Create an item under `/sitecore/content/Applications/` with the `/sitecore/templates/Sitecore Client/Applications/Application` template. Fill in a Display name, choose an `Icon` and optionally a `Tool tip`.
- Open the presentation details of the new item and choose the earlier created layout as `Layout`.
- Under `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Programs`, create a new item based on the `/sitecore/templates/Sitecore Client/Applications/Application shortcut` template.
- Set the `Application` link and a `Display name`. The raw value for Application looks like this in my case:

  ```
  <link text='' linktype='internal' style='' alt=''  querystring='' id='{3585E982-D30B-43EB-93A9-F5F9450FB450}' url="/Applications/Sales"/>
  ```

Make sure you have built the codebehind for your aspx page and that the binary is in the `bin` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail @thomsas-d - that's really helpful.  The only difference between that and what I'd tried was the location of the layout (mine was in `/sitecore/layout/Layouts/User Defined`).  Unfortunately it hasn't helped and the same situation is in place - clicking on the item in the Start Menu doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MarkRadford Can you access the page by going to it directly (without Sitecore)?

Comment: Yes, once logged in, if I browse to the URL I see the page.  (the page inherits from `AdminPage` so it prompts to log in if I've not already done so).